# Update system gsettings programmatically in C++

Tags: proxy, c++, dconf, gsettings

I'm running a service that needs to update the system wide proxy settings on Ubuntu.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'my.proxy.com'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8000
$ gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
```

Currently in my code I'm doing a system call to gsettings but when I read the value back it reads back 'none'. After doing some research I found that this will not work from a service owned by root because the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDR needs to be set.
I also tried Gio::Settings updates but that gave the same results.

Is there a way to set **org.gnome.system.proxy** settings for all users programmatically from C++?

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to do that? I suspect you may have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Running code as root; *really* necessary?  explain why - this might also reveal the same info as @cocomac requests.